# Basic precautions to prevent piracy?

Tags: android, piracy-prevention, anti-piracy, piracy-protection

It's my first app and I am concerned about piracy. I know it's not possible to fully prevent it but I would like to make it as hard that the hacker wouldn't simply find it worth.

I have read some older threads but I don't know how secure Android and libraries like LVL are today.

So far, I have only implemented Proguard and LVL.

What are other ways that people can crack my app besides reverse engineering and what can I do to make it hard?

Also, I asked another question specifically about [lucky patcher piracy prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839983/how-do-i-protect-my-app-against-lucky-patcher-and-anti-lvl). If you know anything about it, please help me there too.

Answer (score 4):

You can stop worrying about it.  Quite frankly-  your code isn't that secret.  Any decent programmer could recreate it.  There aren't hoards of people out there looking to crack your app.  What keeps your app valuable isn't the code its made of, its the understanding of the problem space and continuing resources spent on improving it.  And as long as your code is running on devices you don't own, the most you can even theoretically do is add speed bumps that will cost you more time developing and in maintenance than it would to work around.

Instead, spend your time and effort writing the best app you can, and coming up with new ways for it to provide value for your users.  That's how you'll get actual users.

Your app's data may be valuable.  But you don't protect that by making your app harder to crack, you protect that with real security measures.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are right. I already know that any decent programmer can rewrite it, in fact write it much better than I can. Also one

Comment: *accidentally hit enter there. I'm also gonna price it really low, so that users wouldn't find it worth pirating. I was just worried about those one click tools and easy hacks, that would enable any average person to pry it open and upload on say, aptoide. But, thanks for the suggestion. I should probably stop worrying too much.

Comment: By the way, what security measures to take for protecting user data?

Comment: Depends on what type of data and what threat vector you're scared of.  Protecting the data from remote access is different from physical access, and protecting it from 3rd parties is different than protecting it from the user himself.